# Is there a shorthand version of a selector's "or" for the same element type?

Tags: jquery, selector

Is there short-hand version of:

```
$('input[hasThisAttr], input[hasThatAttr]')
```

I realize that's pretty short, but if you have to check a bunch of common attributes and then ones that differ, it can get pretty verbose.

Comment: @jholloman well, actually you are wrong. Right as it stands there it is selecting inputs having `[hasThisAttr]` OR `[hasThatAttr]` resulting in an array of inputs with `hasThisAttr` AND `hasThatAttr`.

Comment: Yeah I completely failed on my logic there. I was thinking "It will select x and y, so it's an and". Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thought about it more and it looks like filter may be a good option. ex:

```
$("input").filter("[hasThisAttr],[hasThatAttr]")
```

This will grab all inputs then filter based on the list of attr's you specify.